# Comprehensive list of all functional interfaces in JDK outside java.function package

Tags: java, java-8, documentation, java-11, functional-interface

The `java.function` package contains many functional interfaces introduced in Java 8 that are extensively used in the Streams API.

But I know for a fact that by definition there are potentially many other functional interfaces that either

- already existed before Java 8 but now are considered functional because they comply with the definition of a functional interface (having a single abstract method)
- where introduced in Java 8 in other packages besides `java.function`

Examples of the first type are `Runnable`, `ActionLIstener` and `Comparator`.

How can I obtain a **comprehensive** list of all functional interfaces that exist in the Java JDK whether or not they're annotated as @FunctionalInterface

- Is there a programmatic way to get it?
- How can I programmatically produce a list of all interfaces in the JDK that have only one abstract method (even if they have default or static ones)
- There exist such a list?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42973815/2711488