# Why must we use double colons for method references?

Tags: java, java-8

For instance why can I write the line

```
Character[] c = Arrays.sort(list.toArray(new Character[list.size()]))
```

But in documentation when I read about method referencing, they tell me to use `::` instead? Doesn't it do the same as the `.` operator?

I dont know if the above code compiles, as I'm typing this on my mobile. Consider it a loose example.

Comment: ummmmmm... `::` is a syntax error in Java. What documentation did you read?

Comment: Are you reading a tutorial about Java 8 ?

Comment: Could you provide the link where you are read this? It's not Java, it's C++.

Comment: `::` is `C++` syntax, not `Java`...

Comment: @nhgrif Not in Java 8 =)

Comment: @ZouZou, java8 have something like this?

Comment: @msangel http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: *"Beta Draft 2013-10-15
This section was updated to reflect features and conventions of the upcoming Java SE 8 release. You can download the current JDK 8 snapshot from java.net."* This stuff isn't ready yet, if you're new to Java you shouldn't go there yet.

Comment: @msangel Yes, they're called Method Referenes in Java 8.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20001866/1217087) explains how the `::` operator is used in Java 8.

Comment: @Michanne a broader discussion on the :: operator from java 8, you can find here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8/20001548#20001548

Comment: Thanks guys. I reached the point where I was learning about detailed features of classes and methods and stumbled on to method referencing while learning about Lambdas. They should have given it its own section

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The double colon operator is a new operator provided in Java8. It is syntactic sugar that tells the compiler to generate a lambda based on context which will call the method. This makes some lambda expression things a bit easier. Prior to Java8 this operator doesn't exist, and no, its not the same as the dot(.) operator. For example:

```
Math.max(4, 6) // Calls Math.max with the arguments 4 and 6
Math::max // A reference to the max method in the java.lang.Math class
```

For a bit of extra reading (Although this stuff is all in Beta and has not been officially released) try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: That is exactly where I saw it, I was learning about Lambdas and it confused the hell out of me

Comment: It is really to bring Java in line with C++ etc on the whole method pointers and anonymous functions things.

Comment: but what is Math.max, without arguments? couldnt that have served as the desired reference?

Comment: @peter You could legally have a static field called `max` inside `Math` and then the reference would be ambiguous