# How to map strings to URIs?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Let me say that I have a single string concatenated uris.

```
http://...[sp]http://...[sp]http://...
```

I'm trying to convert each split string to URIs.

```java
Stream.of(string.split("\\s")).map(uri -> URI::new);
```

Compiler complains.

```
Cannot infer type-variable(s) R
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: A guess: URI has several constructors, all of which take only String parameters.  All those ctor patterns match your input of a stream of Strings, so it can't choose which one.

Comment: @markspace Confirmed. I don't understand what the constructor with a single String is not chosen.

Answer (score 1):

```
Stream.of(s.split("//s")).map(URI::new);
```

[click here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8)