# An effective way to convert a sequence of Strings to URIs

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

This is a follow up question of [How to map strings to URIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27613957/330457)

I have a `String` of URIs delimited with some white spaces.

```
http://...[sp]http://...[sp]http://...
```

I'm trying to split it and, finally, collect them to a `List`.

I, so far, wrote following codes.

```java
final List<URI> uris = Stream.of(string.split("\\s"))
    .distinct()
    .filter(s -> s.isEmpty())
    .map(s -> {
        try {
            return new URI(s);
        } catch (final URISyntaxException urise) {
            return null;
        }
    })
    .filter(uri -> uri != null)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

My question is,

1. Is `null` creation by URI constructor and following filtering is inevitable?
2. Is there any more effective way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
List<URI> uris = Stream.of(string.split("\\s+")).map(URI::create).collect(
    Collectors.toList());
```

It will throw an exception if any invalid input is encountered, but I'm of the opinion that errors should be exposed, not quietly suppressed.