# Why was the double colon operator chosen for Java 8?

Tags: java, syntax, operators, java-8

Prior to Java 8, my observation was that the de facto standard for referring to member methods was by using the `#` symbol (such as `Object#toString()`). Then along came Java 8 which instead chose the `::` operator for method references for seemingly no reason.

Has there been an official explanation or justification for why `::` in particular was chosen?

Comment: Where has `#` been used to refer to member methods?

Comment: Java has no such thing as "member methods"; functions are not a first class citizen in Java. The `::` was simply borrowed to have a convenient way of defining a method reference, with the left part being a class or instance of it, and the right part being the method name.

Comment: # was never part of Java API standard syntax for refering to methods. You might want to review http://stackoverflow.com/a/22245383/579580 to better understand ::

Comment: Why asking _"Has there been an official explanation or justification for why :: in particular was chosen?"_  is considered as **primarily opinion-based** ?

Comment: @gontard Beats me, but I find that somewhat amusing for some reason. I would ask "how does that qualify as opinion-based?", but then they would probably close this comment too for being primarily opinion-based. :)

Comment: Nevermind... [there is an official explanation or justification](http://openjdk.5641.n7.nabble.com/Method-reference-double-colon-syntax-td58953.html)

Comment: @gontard: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. If this question gets reopened, feel free to post that as an answer (with an excerpt or something to follow the no-link-only guidelines) and I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could find an ["official explanation or justification"](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-May/004979.html) from [Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz). You should read the complete discussion but this is an extract :

> The :: infix syntax:
>
> ```
>    ClassName::methodName 
>    ClassName<T>::methodName 
>    ClassName::<U>genericMethodName
> ```
>
> works acceptably well.  Some people like it, and some people hate it --
> just like #.  There's never going to be a perfect syntax for anything
> that makes everyone jump up in unison and say "yeah, that's it!"  But ::
> is OK, and using up :: here is far better than using up #.  (And, while
> this might look a little weird to C++ programmers, the overlap between
> the Java and C++ developer bases at this point is small enough that I
> don't think we should be too worried about that.)