# What :: mean in java?

Tags: java, keyword

What does "::" do in this code?

```
Files.walk(Paths.get("res")).forEach(System.out::println);
```

I know that we use ':' for an enhanced for loop but I never saw 2 of them together

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8

Answer (score 0):

Double colon :: is called **[Method Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)**.