# What is the best way to print elements of a Collection class?

Tags: java, collections

I am playing around with the Collection API in java, and came through two different ways to print out the elements in the collection. I need to know which would be the best method to be used in any situation.

The first method is to use `.toString()` method (implicitly) in Collection interface. 
The second method is to use iterators and visit each element and print it out. (This code is commented)

```
public class Test  {

    static Set<String> mySet1 = new HashSet<>();
    static Set<String> mySet2 = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       String[] arr = {"hello","world","I","am","Tom"};
       for(int i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
           mySet1.add(arr[i]);
           mySet2.add(arr[i]);
       }

       System.out.println("HashSet prinitng...");
      /* Iterator iter1 = mySet1.iterator();
       while(iter1.hasNext()){
           System.out.println(iter1.next());
       }*/

       System.out.println(mySet1);

       System.out.println("LinkedHashSet printing");
       /*
       Iterator iter2 = mySet2.iterator();
       while(iter2.hasNext()){
           System.out.println(iter2.next());
       }*/

       System.out.println(mySet2);
    }
}
```

Which is better and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8, you can simply:

```
mySet2.forEach(System.out::println);
```

In earlier versions:

```
for (String str : mySet2)
    System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: what does the :: operator mean?

Comment: @DesirePRG [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8) might be useful. This syntax was introduced in Java 8.