# How do I pass a method as a parameter in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I don't understand how to use lambdas to pass a method as a parameter.

Considering the following (not compiling) code, how can I complete it to get it work ?

```
public class DumbTest {
    public class Stuff {
        public String getA() {
            return "a";
        }
        public String getB() {
            return "b";
        }
    }

    public String methodToPassA(Stuff stuff) {
        return stuff.getA();
    }

    public String methodToPassB(Stuff stuff) {
        return stuff.getB();
    }

    //MethodParameter is purely used to be comprehensive, nothing else...
    public void operateListWith(List<Stuff> listStuff, MethodParameter method) {
        for (Stuff stuff : listStuff) {
            System.out.println(method(stuff));
        }
    }

    public DumbTest() {
        List<Stuff> listStuff = new ArrayList<>();
        listStuff.add(new Stuff());
        listStuff.add(new Stuff());

        operateListWith(listStuff, methodToPassA);
        operateListWith(listStuff, methodToPassB);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DumbTest l = new DumbTest();

    }
}
```

Comment: Lambdas only work with functional interfaces (an `interface` with only 1 method, like `Runnable`). I do not see you declaring a functional interface. Also, when you get an error, tell us what error you are getting and where it's at.

Comment: I'm not decalring a functional interface because i'm not understanding it when i wrote this post.. this code is not compiling, it must be read as pseudo code for some parts

Answer (score 6):

Declare your method to accept a parameter of an existing functional interface type which matches your method signature:

```
public void operateListWith(List<Stuff> listStuff, Function<Stuff, String> method) {
    for (Stuff stuff : listStuff) {
        System.out.println(method.apply(stuff));
    }
}
```

and call it as such:

```
operateListWith(listStuff, this::methodToPassA);
```

As a further insight, you don't need the indirection of `methodToPassA`:

```
operateListWith(listStuff, Stuff::getA);
```

Comment: Why would you do this? Why wouldn't you just do `listStuff.stream().map(method).forEach(System.out::println)`? Isn't that the entire point of lambdas?

Comment: I actually prefer OP's way to learning: separating the lambda (a language feature) form Streams (an API which uses it). Lambdas are a far wider story than just the Streams API. Yes, in _production_ code, one would write it your way.

Comment: I'm not using stream because i'd like to understand how to pass a method as a parameter, as Marko guessed it

Comment: This does not work like this ; i get "The method apply(String) in the type Function<String,String> is not applicable for the arguments (DumbTest.Stuff)" compilation error

Comment: Yes, you need `<Stuff, String>` in fact. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Your `MethodParameter` should be some interface you define with a single method.  This is referred to as a functional interface.  You can then pass your methods in.  A quick demonstration:

```
public interface Test{
    void methodToPass(string stuff);
}

[...]

public class DumbTest{
     //MethodParameter is purely used to be comprehensive, nothing else...
    public void operateListWith(List<Stuff> listStuff, Test method) {
        for (Stuff stuff : listStuff) {
            System.out.println(method(stuff));
        }
    }
    public DumbTest() {
        List<Stuff> listStuff = new ArrayList<>();
        //fill list
        operateListWith(listStuff, methodToPassA);
        operateListWith(listStuff, methodToPassB);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The definition of `MethodParameter` is missing from your source code. To be used with lambda expressions, it must be a functional interface, for example:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface MethodParameter {
    String apply(Stuff input);
}
```

(The `@FunctionalInterface` annotation is optional.)

To use the method, you have call the method from the interface:

```
System.out.println(method.apply(stuff));
```

And thirdly, a method reference always needs a context. In your case you have to do:

```
operateListWith(listStuff, this::methodToPassA);
operateListWith(listStuff, this::methodToPassB);
```

Answer (score 1):

### You need to use [method references.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8/20001866#20001866)

You don't need to create a method like `operateListWith`, that's sort of the whole idea. Instead, you can operate on each value using [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) by doing  something like this:

```
listStuff.stream.forEach(object::methodToPassA);
```

For example:

```
public class StreamExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Hello", "What's Up?", "GoodBye");
    list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello
What's Up?
GoodBye
```

In your case, you can get the value inside `Stuff` using [`.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-), and then operate on it using `forEach`, like this:

```
public class DumbTest {
  public class Stuff {
    public String getA() {
      return "a";
    }

    public String getB() {
      return "b";
    }
  }

  public String methodToPassA(Stuff stuff) {
    return stuff.getA();
  }

  public String methodToPassB(Stuff stuff) {
    return stuff.getA();
  }

  public DumbTest() {
    List<Stuff> listStuff = Arrays.asList(new Stuff(), new Stuff());

    listStuff.stream()
        .map(this::methodToPassA)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    DumbTest l = new DumbTest();
  }
}
```