# what's the meaning of the symbols "::","->" in java

Tags: java

I found someone uses the two symbols (`::`,`->`) in Java, I don't know this syntax, could anyone help to explain it, and tell me where the doc can find?

I've found a previous question about the symbol `::`, but I don't find the meaning of the symbol `->`, could someone help to answer it?

Comment: Read about lambda expressions and method references (Java 8).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8

Comment: Thanks, and I want to know the meaning of "->", could you help to explain it?

Comment: @Rophie https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html