# Java 8 Lambdas max() on stream using Integer.max as comparator

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have written simple `List` with example values, and I wanted the stream to return max value from Stream. I know `max()` function takes `Comparator` but it turned out, I can pass also `Integer::max` (anyone can explain my, why?).

Moreover, program prints weird result, I inspected it "inside" and it looks OK, but after I get final result - they are not accurate.

Example:

```
@Test
public void testHowIntegerMaxWorksInStream() {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(5,3,8);
    Optional<Integer> op = list.stream().max((a, b) -> {
        System.out.println("Input arguments a=" + a + ", b=" + b);

        int max = Integer.max(a, b);
        System.out.println("Returning max(a,b)=" + max);
        return max;
    });
    System.out.println("Optional result=" + op.get());
}
```

Output:

```
Input arguments a=5, b=3
Returning max(a,b)=5
Input arguments a=5, b=8
Returning max(a,b)=8 // OK, Integer::max got 8.. but then ...
Optional result=5 // .. I got 5. WHY ???
```

My questions:

1. Why can I pass `Integer::max` in place of `Comparator` ?
2. Why my function returns 5 as a result while inside it's 8 ?

Comment: You should be using `Integer::conmpareTo`, not `Integer::max`...

Comment: Alternatively you could use `reduce(Integer::max);` since taking the maximum is an associative operation, but this is pretty much the same as `max(Integer::compare)`

Comment: The answer to 1): That's how method references work. If the signature of the method is suitable, you can do it; There's no "intelligent check" that prevents this. The answer to 2): If you tell the `max` method that `5>3>8` and `5>8` this is what you get...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you create [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html%20Comparator) that always returns the first element to be the greatest.

If you compare `A` and `B`, you should return `-1` if `A` is smaller. You return the `Integer.max` of `A` and `B`, which, in your case, is always `>0`.

```
(a,b) -> { 
   if (a>b) return 1;     // <-- you return a positive value always, so stream.max() thinks 5>8 :)
   if (a<b) return -1;
   if (a==b) return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ahhh! I see! To sum it up: Output of my max function should return `-1`, `0` or `1` and what I have here is to ALWAYS return positive number. Therefore first argument, here calling `a` always wins. Am I right?

Comment: @mlewandowski yes. You can also experiment with negative values in your list to see what happens ;)

Comment: The output doesn’t have to be strictly `-1` or `+1`. It can be any integer value but what matters is the meaning of the result being negative, zero or positive.

Comment: @Holger yes that is correct, thanks for adding the comment . I just simplified it for this example.

Answer (score 8):

You're misunderstanding things. [`max(comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max-java.util.Comparator-) takes a comparator that compares integer. What you're doing is not comparing integers, i.e. telling if `a` is greater than `b` or not. You're taking the max of them and returning it. So you're saying that `a` is always greater than `b`, since you're always returning a positive number (your list only consists of positive numbers). A [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) returns:

> a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

What you need to do is

```
public void testHowIntegerMaxWorksInStream() {
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(5,3,8);
    Optional<Integer> op = list.stream().max((a, b) -> {
        int compare = Integer.compare(a, b);
        return compare;
    });
    System.out.println("Optional result=" + op.get());
}
```

i.e. calling [`Integer.compare`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) instead of `max`, which does exactly that:

> Compares its two arguments for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the second.

For the second part of your question, refer to [:: (double colon) operator in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8). It is called a method-refence. So another way to write it is:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(5,3,8);
Optional<Integer> op = list.stream().max(Integer::compare);
System.out.println("Optional result=" + op.get());
```

Answer (score 5):

The reason that `Integer.max`, unfortunately, compiles in place of a comparator is that its return type fits what is expected by stream's `max` method: the result of a comparison is an `int`, and the result of comparing two `int`s is an `int` as well. However, the result returned by `Integer.max` is inconsistent with what stream's `max` expects, which explains incorrect result: for example, if you pass `(5, 8)` to `Integer.max` it returns `8`, a positive number; stream's `max`, however, interprets all positive numbers as an indication that the first parameter is greater than the second, which is incorrect in this situation.

The only reason why this compiles is that your comparator returns an `int`. This wouldn't work with `Double` or `BigInteger`.