# Java process array in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing

I have an array I want to process in different ways in parallel to speed up the overall runtime of my program.  Here is what the program looks like when doing everything sequentially.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<MyObject> array = getLongListOfObjects();
    ArrayList<MyObject2> array2 = new ArrayList<MyObject2>();
    for(MyObject object : array) {
         array2.add(firstProcessingMethod(object);
    }
    ArrayList<MyObject3> array3 = new ArrayList<MyObject3>();
    for(MyObject2 object : array2) {
         array3.add(secondProcessingMethod(object);
    }
    ArrayList<MyObject4> array4 = new ArrayList<MyObject4>();
    for(MyObject3 object : array3) {
         array4.add(thirdProcessingMethod(object);
    }
    for(MyObject4 object : array4) {
         System.out.println(object.toString());
    }
}
```

In other words I want to start processing the array with `firstProcessingMethod()` and after the first iteration I can start running `secondProcessingMethod()` and `thirdProcessingMethod()` while the rest of the array is still going through `firstProcessingMethod()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Java 8, you can use Streams.

```
array.parallelStream()
    .map(ThisClass::firstProcessingMethod)
    .map(ThisClass::secondProcessingMethod)
    .map(ThisClass::thirdProcessingMethod)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: What is ThisClass:: referring to?

Comment: It's referring to the class that contains those methods. It's kind of like passing a method as a parameter. For more information, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8)