# What does the :: mean in Java?

Tags: java

While looking at some open source project for Java, I find a statement "connectAsync::getConnection", I googled but could not find what's the purpose for :: operator?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting.