# double colon assignment on method with two parameters

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I am using lamdbas so I can consistently set the properties of a ModelObject according to the values I can retrieve from three different objects. The code works like this:

```
public class Processor {

    private void bar(Setter setter, MyClass myObject) {
        String variable = myObject.getStringByABunchOfMethods();
        setter.setVariable(variable);
    }

    protected void foo(...) {
        ...
        bar(value -> model.setA(CONSTANT, value), aObject);
        bar(value -> model.setB(value), bObject);
        bar(value -> model.setC(value), cObject);
        ...
    }

    private interface Setter {
        public void setVariable(String string);
    }

}

public interface IModel {
    public void setA(String arg0, String arg1);
    public void setB(String arg0);
    public void setC(String arg0);
}
```

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8) that it is possible to rewrite `bar(value -> model.setB(value), bObject);` to `bar(model::setB, bObject)`. I think this looks better and more concise, but I haven't found a way to rewrite the `setA` method to a double :: notation. Can anyone tell me if this is possible, and if so: how is this possible?

Comment: Please refer this [Method References Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html). Shows all kinds of method references. Hope this helps

Comment: I do not think it is possible.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html and https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/tutorials/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx

There would be 4 different kinds of method references.  The corresponding lambda and method reference:

- (args) -> Class.staticMethod(args), Class::staticMethod
- (obj, args) -> obj.instanceMethod(args), ObjectType::instanceMethod
- (args) -> obj.instanceMethod(args), obj::instanceMethod
- (args) -> new ClassName(args), ClassName::new

The lambda **value -> model.setA(CONSTANT, value)** does not correspond with any of the lambdas above, so it is not possible to rewrite it as a method reference.

Comment: The reason why I accepted this answer is: while the other answers are clever and useful, they don't make my code more understandable or cleaner. So I'll stick to using the `->` notation.

Answer (score 4):

To use the double colon notation, the method that you're referencing must have the same signature as the required method. So you can't use `::` unless you change your `IModel`:

You can add an overload of `setA` in `IModel`:

```
default void setA(String arg0) {
    setA(CONSTANT, arg0);
}
```

Then, you can reference that overload:

```
bar(model::setA, aObject);
```

.

Comment: To change the `IModel` would be too much work in order to use a cleaner notation in this case. I hadn't seen the `default` keyword before, so I'll look into that for the future!

Answer (score 3):

Not with the way the `Setter` functional interface is written. Unlike `setB` and `setC`, the `setA` method expects two arguments whereas the interface `Setter` has a method expecting only one argument. You can add another interface that accepts two arguments:

```
private interface SetterWithDefault {
    public void setVariable(String defaultString, String string);
}
```

Then you can call it via the `bar` method:

```
private void bar(SetterWithDefault setter, String defaultString, MyClass myObject) {
    String variable = myObject.getStringByABunchOfMethods();
    setter.setVariable(defaultString, variable);
}
```

Then you can call `bar` as follows:

```
bar(model::setA, CONSTANT, aObject);
```

**Note:** You can keep the other `bar` method. The new one can be an overload.

Comment: But what should be done with the other `bar` calls that the OP listed without the `CONSTANT` parameter?

Comment: @Sweeper He can keep the other `bar` method. It's simply an overloaded method.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a special interface: `setB` is a `Consumer<String>` and `setA` is a `BiConsumer<String, String>`. You can then adapt a `BiConsumer` to a `Consumer`:

Either with a default method in your interface (if `setA` is always called with a constant, why not ?):

```
interface Model {
    public void setA(String arg0, String arg1);
    default void setA(String arg1) {setA(CONSTANT, arg1);}
    public void setB(String arg0);
    public void setC(String arg0);
}
```

Either using an adapter of `BiConsumer` to `Consumer`:

```
static <T, U> Consumer<V> adapt(T t, BiConsumer<T, U> biConsumer) {
  Objects.requireNonNull(biConsumer, "biConsumer");
  Objects.requireNonNull(t, "t");
  return t -> biConsummer.accept(t, u);
}
```

And using it like this:

```
 protected void foo(...) {
   ...
   bar(adapt(CONSTANT, model::setA), aObject);
   bar(model::setB, bObject);
   bar(model::setC, cObject);
   ...
 }
```

**Note:** I used `adapt` as an example name, but that's a bad name when you mix it with other `adapt` overload method (because of generic and type erasure). I personally name it like `fixLeftValue`.

Beware that the `adapt` will be generated each time you invoke `foo`.