# How method reference work in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

There is an introduction of :: operator in Java 8.  Which can be used to refer any static, instance or constructor method. 
I found it really confusing. What is the actual thing running behind? And what is the flow of execution. Someone explain with example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8/20001866

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html