# Java double colon operator from compile time to byte code generation?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8) the author uses the following example:

```
@Override
public final OptionalInt max() {
    return reduce(Math::max); //this is the gotcha line
}
```

So in this case it looks as if `max()` is a proxy for `Math.max` on the instance of this class.  However there are no arguments passed to max, so does java 8 compile this to something like (Pseudo code):

```
@Override
public final OptionalInt max(Integer a, Integer b) {
      //If neither a or b are null
      return new OptionalInt.of(Math.max(a,b));
      //Otherwise return empty because we can't compare the numbers
      return OptionalInt.empty()
}
```

Also how would one write the javadoc for something like this?

Comment: Why does it have two returns statements? Only the first one will be used

Comment: I just left off the if else part ... If neither a or b are null (Just did not code it)

Comment: *"there are no arguments passed to max"* What makes you think that? The `Math::max` method reference is implementing the `applyAsInt(int left, int right)` of the `IntBinaryOperator` parameter to the `reduce` method, i.e. when `op.applyAsInt(a, b)` is called, it calls `Math.max(a, b)`. --- In this particular case, `Math::max` is virtually the same as the anonymous class `new IntBinaryOperator() { public int applyAsInt(int left, int right) { return Math.max(left, right); } }`

Comment: Doesn't the Q&A you linked to basically answer this? Your example of how you think this might be compiled at least shows you haven't read the answers there.

Comment: That makes sense.  It's just a bit magical ... When reading the code we only see Math::max being passed to reduce.  After that we call instance.max() and presumably that operates on the array instance we are wrapping and reduces it to a single value if possible, but it still just looks magical so I'm trying to figure out a good way to wrap my peanut brain around it :)

Comment: wait... so the only thing you were missing is `Math::max`? you could think about it as `(int x, int y) -> Math.max(x,y)` and now you have arguments. But the answer there already does that; as such this should be close as a duplicated of that

Comment: That part I understand.  The part that looks like magic is the reduce(Math::max) part ... I think ultimately we are running a bunch of values that reduce ( or not since it's Optional) by calling max on the instance...So the part I'm missing I think is how reduce gets coupled to the data that the instance is holding?  In other words I'm used to seeing function(data) { do stuff with data} ... but in this case we don't see that ...

Comment: 1) Ole first you have to tag someone by `@` - you've been here quite a lot, u should now that. 2) look at `ReduceOps#makeInt` - that's creating the terminal Sink that elements will be fed to. There's a lot to read and understand here (I still don't get it entirely in it's full glory), but `IntPipeline` is *not holding* any elements, they will be pulled one by one *from the source* (by `Spliterator#forEachRemaning`)

Comment: Thanks @Eugene - it's becoming a lot clearer now.

Comment: Actually now that I'm looking at it in the context of the answer I think I was making a it a lot more complicated than it is :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So in this case it looks as if `max()` is a proxy for `Math.max` on the instance of this class.  However there are no arguments passed to max, so does java 8 compile this to something like (Pseudo code):
>
> ```
> @Override
> public final OptionalInt max(Integer a, Integer b) {
>       //If neither a or b are null
>       return new OptionalInt.of(Math.max(a,b));
>       //Otherwise return empty because we can't compare the numbers
>       return OptionalInt.empty()
> }
> ```

Not quite :).  Let's start by figuring out what the `reduce` operator *actually does*.  The documentation explains that it performs a *reduction* on a sequence of numbers by applying an algorithm that is logically equivalent to the following:

```
public OptionalInt reduce(IntBinaryOperator op) {
    boolean foundAny = false;
    int result = 0;

    for (int element : [this stream]) {
        if (!foundAny) {
            foundAny = true;
            result = element;
        }
        else {
            result = op.applyAsInt(result, element);
        }
    }

    return foundAny ? OptionalInt.of(result)
                    : OptionalInt.empty();
}
```

Seems simple enough.  If you can tell it how to take *two* numbers and 'reduce' or 'combine' them into one, then `reduce` knows how to extend that logic to reduce *an entire sequence* into a single number.  It handles the edge cases and the aggregation for you.  All it needs from you is a function that takes in two numbers and gives it one back.  That function should conform to the functional interface `IntBinaryOperator`.

A *functional interface* is an interface that is meant to describe a single function.  Specifically, it describes the argument types and the return type.  The rest is largely superfluous.  The signature for an `IntBinaryOperator` looks like this:

```
int applyAsInt(int left, int right);
```

You can provide a function that conforms to this specification in several ways.  Prior to Java 8, you might have done something like this:

```
stream.reduce(
    new IntBinaryOperator() {
        public int applyAsInt(int a, int b) {
            return b > a ? b : a;
        }
    }
);
```

Java 8 gives us a shorthand form for functional interfaces called *lambda expressions*.  These are a bit more concise, and while they are conceptually *similar* to anonymous inner classes, they're not quite the same thing.

```
stream.reduce((a, b) -> b > a ? b : a);
```

Both functions above are equivalent: they take in two numbers and return the larger of the two.  As it turns out, every standard programming library has a function that does exactly the same thing.  In Java, that function is `Math.max`.  So rather than writing this logic myself, I can *delegate* to `Math.max`:

```
stream.reduce((a, b) -> Math.max(a, b));
```

But wait!  All `reduce` wants is a function that takes two numbers and returns one.  `Math.max` does that, so do I even need to wrap it in a lambda?  It turns out I don't; I can tell `reduce` to just call `Math.max` directly:

```
stream.reduce(Math::max);
```

This says "I know you want a function, so I'm show you *by name* where to find one that's already been written".  The compiler knows that `Math.max` conforms to the `(int, int) -> int` specification we need, so it emits some bytecode telling the VM how to 'bootstrap' it once it's needed.  When the JVM hits your call to `reduce`, it calls a special method that generates a wrapper class implementing `IntBinaryOperator` that delegates to `Math.max` in its implementation of `applyAsInt`.  It only performs this 'bootstrapping' step once.  Since calling `Math.max` doesn't rely on anything other than the two numbers that get passed in, it can cache that implementation and use it the next time you wind up on this code path.

Comment: Great answer - thanks for elaborating further!  - Just curious whether you could also elaborate on this syntax as I've never seen it before: `[this stream]` .... it looks like it's a reference to a member of the class that is a integer stream ...  Perhaps this would be better as a separate question ...

Comment: @Ole thats not a syntax :) its a simple example

Comment: Right, "[this stream]" was a bit of pseudocode.  You can't actually iterate over a stream with a loop like that.  That code was for illustrative purposes only :).

Answer (score 2):

Pre Java 8, this would have been written as:

```
public MyMathInteface {
    OptionalInt max(Integer a, Integer b);
}

public static final MyMathInterface reducing = new MyMathInterface() {
    @Override
    public OptionalInt max(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return OptionalInt.of(Math.max(a, b));
    }
};

@Override
public final OptionalInt max() {
    return reduce(reducing);
}
```

Then reduce would be defined as:

```
public static OptionalInt reduce(MyMathInteface toReduce) {
    return toReduce.max(someValueA, someValueB);
}
```

So to answer your question, no arguments are passed to `Math::max`, because those values are retrieved by the `reduce` function. They could be constants or they could be retrieved from some other place.

In any case, the use of the max method in this way is called a method reference, that is where you do `SomeObject::method`. That `::` operator creates a method reference. It returns a function, but does not call the function. The user (reduce) is responsible for calling the function.