# Comparator.comparing not working without Method reference in java 8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, stream, comparator

```
List<Animal> animals = this.service.findAll();
animals = animals.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Animal::getName)).collect(Collectors.toList());

//working
```

while

```
List<Animal> animals = this.service.findAll();
animals = animals.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Animal.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());

//Not working..
```

Can any one tell me why i cant use comparator comparing without Method Reference ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably not compiling unless `getName()` is a static method.

If you don't want to use a method reference (it's not syntatic sugar) use a lambda this should also work.

```
animals.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.getName()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: please mark this as the answer if it worked for you thanks

Answer (score 6):

[`Comparator#comparing`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-)

> ***Accepts a function that extracts a Comparable sort key*** from a type T,
>   and returns a Comparator that compares by that sort key.

`Animal::getName` gives the method reference whereas `Animal.getName()` give you a `String` (probably).

Reference :

[:: (double colon) operator in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8)