# How to pass a function as a parameter in java

Tags: java

I have a matrix class and I want to create a function called map in this class, that looks something like this

```
  public void map(T fn) {
      //do something
   }
```

the idea behind the function is that as a parameter fn, which could be any method and apply this method to each number in the matrix.

the Idea behind it was for the coding train videos on a neural network but I tried to manipulate it in Java and it didn't work.I search lambda expressions but when I use it it's only let me pass method like Math.cos(arg) with an argument inside.
but I want it to pass without any arguments
the current function looks like this

```
interface lambda<T> {
double foo(T fn);
}

public void map(T fn) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i< this.getRow() ; i++) {
        for(int j = 0 ; j< this.getCol(); j++) {
            int a = i;
            int b = j;
            lambda mycode = (T) -> setData(matrix[a][b], fn);
            matrix[i][j] = mycode.foo(fn);
        }
    }
}
private double setData(double data, T fn) {
    data = (double) fn;
    return data;
}
```

when I send a call from my main class I can only call with arguments like

```
matrix.map(Math.cos(matrix.getData(0,0))
```

but it apply on each value in the matrix the cos of data at 0,0

I wish it will look more like this

```
matrix.map(Math.cos())
```

or even

```
Matrix.map(function())
```

is there a way in java to pass methods as parameters without entering arguments in them?

Comment: The syntax is `Math::cos`

Comment: I tried to switch math.cos it with math::cos but I get an error "The target type of this expression must be a functional interface"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 8 was shipped with enormous number of [functional interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html). You can use one of those to describe the expected function to be passed as parameter in your method.

In your case, for passing a function which excepts a single `double` parameter and applys a logic, use [java.util.function.DoubleUnaryOperator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/IntBinaryOperator.html):

```
static double foo(DoubleUnaryOperator fn){
    double aNumber = 2.0;  
    return fn.applyAsDouble(aNumber);
}
```

And then create a lambda (or an object which implements `DoubleUnaryOperator`) and pass it to the `foo` method:

```
foo(d -> d * 3);
```

or

```
public class Fn implements DoubleUnaryOperator {
    @Override
    public double applyAsDouble(double d) {
        return d * 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [:: operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8), to pass method reference, such as

```
Math::cos
```

Also, you need to make sure, method where you are passing method reference, should accept [functional interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html)

That said,

```
void map(Consumer<T> fn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional programming in Java is backed by functional interfaces (interfaces with only one abstract method) and lamdas. There are several built-in functional interfaces provided by java. You can use [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) / [DoubleFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/DoubleFunction.html) those interfaces has one abstract method Function#apply. You can also create your own functional interfaces but it is better to use the existing solution provided by API if it fulfills your requirements. Please refer Below is the code sample you may get clarity.

```
public void map(DoubleFunction<Double> fn) {
  //do something
  setData(10.0, Math::cos);
 //do something
}
private double setData(double data,  DoubleFunction<Double> fn) {
    data = fn.apply(data);
    return data;
}
```