# Java 8 Pass void parameter to method

Tags: java, parameters, arguments, void

I want to pass void parameter to another void method.
For example;

```
public void WriteItem(ParameterItem())
{
System.out.println("1");
ParameterItem();
System.ou.println("2");
}

//In Another Class
public void ParameterItem()
{
System.out.println("ABC");
}
```

I want this:
1
ABC
2

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to make `ParameterItem()` (or `parameterItem()` for proper naming) return the value you want it to print, rather than having the printing functionality built in?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass a function as a parameter in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48594418/how-to-pass-a-function-as-a-parameter-in-java)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/4685606/2400380

Comment: ParametersItem is void method thats return nothing