# What is the difference between Comparator::reverseOrder and Comparator.reverseOrder() when used in sorted method of stream

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream, comparator

What is the difference between `Comparator::reverseOrder` and `Comparator.reverseOrder()` when used in sorted method of stream.

```
    Stream<String> streamText = Stream.of("over the river", "through the woods", "to grandmother's house we go");
```

This works:

```
    streamText.filter(n -> n.startsWith("t"))
         .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
         .findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

But this does not compile:

```
    streamText.filter(n -> n.startsWith("t"))
         .sorted(Comparator::reverseOrder)
         .findFirst().ifPresent(System.out::println);
```

Comment: [`sorted`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted-java.util.Comparator-) accepts a `Comparator` as its argument. [`Comparator::reverseOrder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#reverseOrder--) is not a comparator. It is a method that _returns_ a comparator. So you need to call it and pass the return value to `sorted`.

Comment: One is a method invocation and the other is a method reference. They're not interchangeable. It would help if you could explain why you think that `sorted(Comparator::reverseOrder)` should be able to compile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good question!

`sorted` need a `Comparator<T>`, right? `Comparator<T>` is a functional interface. It represents a function that takes 2 arguments and returns an `int` indicating which argument is greater or whether they are equal.

In the case of `Comparator.reverseOrder()`, `reverseOrder` is a method that returns a `Comparator<T>`. In this case you call the method and it returns a `Comparator` that can be used as the parameter for `sorted`. Everything is good.

In the case of `Comparator::reverseOrder`, you are not calling `reverseOrder`. Instead, you are passing `reverseOrder` as a function into `sorted`. As mentioned above, `sorted` will accept a function that takes 2 parameters and returns an `int`, but you are giving it `reverseOrder`, which takes no arguments and returns a `Comparator<T>`. See the mismatch here?

> Expected: a function that takes 2 parameters and returns an int OR a `Comparator<T>` object
>
> What you gave it: a function that takes no parameters and returns a `Comparator<T>`

This results in a compiler error.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining. :). I got it. :: is a method reference and the other is a method call. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8

Comment: Very well explained! :)