# Is there a difference between these lines of code

Tags: java, lambda

Is there a difference between these lines of code, and what is best to use it?
thanks

```
public static void main( String[] args ){
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> component.method() ); }
```

vs

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      public void run(){
            component.method();
    }} );
}
```

or

```
public static void main( String[] args ) {
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
      public void run(){
            component::method();
    }} );
}
```

Comment: The third one won't compile.

Comment: There are differences, yes. But the last one will not compile (should probably be `invokeLater(component::method);`)

Comment: For the first two read this: https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-8-lambda-thread-runnable-syntax-examples
For the last one, read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8

Comment: Only difference between method invocation inside lambda function and direct method reference is a one more line in a StackTrace.

Answer (score 4):

The last one doesn't pass compilation.

Using either lambda expression

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> component.method());
```

or method reference

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(component::method);
```

is shorter than the second one, which makes them preferable in Java 8 and later.