# How can I get Predicate from static methods via reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, predicate

Given a class consisting of static predicate methods, I want to access them via reflection and convert them to `Predicate<Object>` type.

```
public class MyPredicates {
    public static boolean isNull(Object obj) {
        return obj == null;
    }

    public static boolean hasNegativeHashcode(Object obj) {
        return obj.hashCode() < 0;
    }
}
```

Normally, I would write the following code to get the predicate:

```
Predicate<Object> isNull = MyPredicates::isNull;
```

However, I don't know how to do that using reflection. My intention is to create an annotation for these methods and get them via reflection to create a list of available predicates for my framework.

I thought of three possible approaches, none of which seems good to me.

1. I could leave it like `Method`, call `invoke()` and cast the returned `Object` to `boolean`. This, however, would be hard to read and it would mean that I'd have no way of checking the type during runtime.
2. I could wrap the reflection call to `Predicate` but this would involve additional overhead.
3. I could make the user to register every method separately (hard to maintain when adding/removing many methods).

In any case, I fear that using reflection directly will add more overhead and slow down the program.

So, my questions are:

1. Can I get the `Predicate` via reflection directly?
2. If not, what would be an appropriate way of accessing such methods without adding too much overhead, while having a usable API (e.g. by involving `Predicate`)?

Comment: I don’t understand why you need reflection.  Won’t your annotation processor know what `@NotNull` (or whatever you choose to call it) does?

Comment: @VGR My point is not to make `@NotNull` annotation, but to get an array of `Predicate` which the user would create. For example, I could have 100 different predicate methods stored in the array for later use (not described here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Return `Predicate` directly from a static method and store it for future use (possibly in a map with method names as keys) to eliminate speed bottleneck of reflective access.

```
public static Predicate<Object> isNull() {
    return obj -> obj == null;
}
```

---

First of all, it's important to understand how JVM handles method references. There is a great [explanation of that in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20001866/4581323). Take a look at the [lambda translation document](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-translation.html) - in particular, section *Method reference capture*.

> ```
> list.filter(String::isEmpty)
> ```
>
> is translated as
>
> ```
> list.filter(indy(MH(metaFactory), MH(invokeVirtual Predicate.apply), MH(invokeVirtual String.isEmpty))()))
> ```

This means that `Predicate` doesn't exist during runtime unless you write it in your code. There could be a convenient way to get it via reflection API but as far as I know, there isn't. You may be able to write something similar using [dynamic proxies](https://www.baeldung.com/java-dynamic-proxies); however, I think it would add unnecessary complexity to the code.

Here is a benchmark of 4 different methods to achieve the desired behaviour, including those mentioned in the question:

```
Benchmark                                     Mode  Cnt    Score    Error   Units
MyBenchmark.testNormal                       thrpt   30  362.782 ± 13.521  ops/us
MyBenchmark.testReflectionInvoke             thrpt   30   60.440 ±  1.394  ops/us
MyBenchmark.testReflectionWrappedPredicate   thrpt   30   62.948 ±  0.846  ops/us
MyBenchmark.testReflectionReturnedPredicate  thrpt   30  381.780 ±  5.265  ops/us
```

1. **testNormal** accesses the predicate via `::` operator
2. **testReflectionInvoke** uses the `invoke()` method directly
3. **testReflectionWrappedPredicate** wraps the `invoke()` method to `Precicate`
4. **testReflectionReturnedPredicate** uses a method which returns `Predicate`, so reflection is invoked only once

The predicates were cached for the purpose of this example, since we are not testing the speed of getting a predicate but assuming it'll be done only once.

As you can see from the results, reflection is 6 times slower than accessing predicates normally. Therefore, in my opinion, **the cleanest/most maintainable way to do this is to have methods with no arguments which return `Predicate` type** instead of `boolean`.

```
public static Predicate<Object> isNull() {
    return obj -> obj == null;
}
```

---

The benchmark has been done using 3 forks, 4 warm-up iterations and 10 iterations.

Here is the code I used for testing, if you want to run the benchmark yourself (uses JMH framework to do the benchmarking):

```
public class MyBenchmark {
    public static Predicate<Object> normal = MyBenchmark::isNull;
    public static Method reflectionInvoke;
    public static Predicate<Object> reflectionWrappedPredicate;
    public static Predicate<Object> reflectionReturnedPredicate;

    static {
        try {
            Method m1 = MyBenchmark.class.getMethod("isNull", Object.class);
            reflectionInvoke = m1;
            reflectionWrappedPredicate = a -> {
                try {
                    return (boolean)m1.invoke(null, a);
                }
                catch(IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
                    return false;
                }
            };

            Method m2 = MyBenchmark.class.getMethod("isNull");
            reflectionReturnedPredicate = (Predicate)m2.invoke(null);
        }
        catch(IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        };
    }

    @Benchmark
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
    public boolean testNormal() {
        Predicate<Object> p = normal;
        return p.test(this) | p.test(null);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
    public boolean testReflectionInvoke() {
        try {
            Method m = reflectionInvoke;
            return (boolean)m.invoke(null, this) | (boolean)m.invoke(null, (Object)null);
        }
        catch(IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | SecurityException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Benchmark
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
    public boolean testReflectionWrappedPredicate() {
        Predicate<Object> p = reflectionWrappedPredicate;
        return p.test(this) | p.test(null);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)
    public boolean testReflectionReturnedPredicate() {
        Predicate<Object> p = reflectionReturnedPredicate;
        return p.test(this) | p.test(null);
    }

    public static boolean isNull(Object obj) {
        return obj == null;
    }

    public static Predicate<Object> isNull() {
        return obj -> obj == null;
    }
}
```