# Java - Do the function receives the parameter internally when using the::?

Tags: java, java-8

I have some confusion and want to clear my concept.

Let say we the following statement:

`.map(i -> Tests.doubleIt(i))`

So, when using the `::` as:

`.map(Tests::doubleIt)`

So, do the `i` parameter is internally received by the `doubleIt` and internally passed to `doubleIt` method?

Can we know the internals how the `i` is received and passed to the `doubleIt` method in case of `::`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "internally received". But `map` expects the input of exactly *one* argument, and the return of a certain type. By writing `Tests::doubleIt` the compiler searches for a method with the name `doubleIt` within `Tests` which accepts *one* argument and returns a certain type.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20001866/7972699  read this will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in `map` calls the function you pass it (`doubleIt`) passing it the argument directly, which `doubleIt` receives as its first formal parameter. In contrast, with your lambda version, `map` calls your lambda with the argument, which your lambda receives as its `i` parameter, and then your lambda calls `doubleIt` using `i` as the argument. So it's more direct with the method reference (in theory) than with the lambda.

Comment: What if we have more that one parameters?

Comment: @user10796624 - It's exactly the same situation. The method you pass in must match what `map` is expecting (in `map`'s case, a method with a single formal parameter of type `int` [if I'm not mistaken]). But if you're calling a method that expects a callback that accepts multiple parameters, then of course when it calls that method, it will pass it multiple arguments, one for each parameter.

Comment: and all the multiple parameters will be placed into their own places for example `p1`, `p1`, `p3` will be `doubleIt(p1,p2,p3)`, is i am correct?

Comment: @user10796624 - Of course. It's just a method call. There's nothing special about it.

Answer (score 1):

> So, do the i parameter is internally received by the doubleIt and
>   internally passed to doubleIt method?

```
.map(i -> Tests.doubleIt(i))
```

the above line reads as "given an element represent as `i`, call the `doubleIt` method with the current element as input".

In other words, you're specifying the "what" should be done and the "how" it should be done is an internal implementation detail.

> Can we know the internals how the i is received and passed to the
>   doubleIt method in case of ::?

When you pass `Tests::doubleIt` you're essentially passing a "reference" to the `doubleIt` method and for each element of the source the `map` method will invoke the  `doubleIt` function passing the current element as input.

There's nothing more to it.

Readings you may find useful:

- [Java 8 Method Reference: How to Use it](https://www.codementor.io/eh3rrera/using-java-8-method-reference-du10866vx)
- [An Introduction to Functional Programming in Java 8](https://flyingbytes.github.io/programming/java8/functional/part1/2017/01/23/Java8-Part1.html)
- [Java 8: An Introduction to Streams](https://www.gravytrain.co.uk/blog/java-8-introduction-streams/)

Comment: And all this is done `internally`, no need to do extra work for it, right?

Comment: @user10796624 yes, the main idea of functional programming as of JDK8 is the user only specifies the "what" and the "how" is an internal implementation detail.

Comment: @user10796624 you're welcome. added some few blogs which you might find useful. all the best :)

Answer (score 0):

It gets simpler when you consider the functional interface type and the stream value itself in isolation.

**On the one hand**, Suppose a simplistic custom class that holds an integer and has a `map` method:

```
class MyObject {
    int value = 0;

    MyObject map(Function<Integer, Integer> f) {
        this.value = f.apply(this.value);
        return this;
    }
}
```

This `MyObject` class knows the element it holds, so when its `map` method is executed, the class knows where to find the value that the function will take as parameter. Roughly speaking, this is also how streams use the function.

**On the other hand**, there's the creation of a `Function<Integer, Integer>` instance that will be passed to `map`.
As you pointed out, you can use `Tests::doubleIt` or `i -> Tests.doubleIt(i)` to supply the argument to `map` (in this case, it doesn't matter which method, the resulting `Function` object will be called in the same way).

What I'm trying to get at: these are two are separate concerns: `MyObject` will know how to source the elements passed to `Function.apply` while the class calling `map` will be responsible for supplying the logic. This "logic" is the `Function` instance.

When you look at the two in isolation, the answer to your question becomes obvious. I believe it will help to implement similar code.