# Can someone unpack this very terse Java function into a more verbose example?

Tags: java, xojo

I'm trying to port [this Java tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-a-star-pathfinding) to Xojo. I'm struggling to unpack the `Set` function below because, whilst short and elegant, it crams a lot of conversions into a small space and I'm not sure if I'm understanding it correctly. It's difficult as Java is not my primary language and Xojo lacks support for generics:

```
public interface GraphNode {
    String getId();
}


public class Graph<T extends GraphNode> {
    private final Set<T> nodes;
    private final Map<String, Set<String>> connections;

    public T getNode(String id) {
        return nodes.stream()
            .filter(node -> node.getId().equals(id))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No node found with ID"));
    }

    public Set<T> getConnections(T node) {
        return connections.get(node.getId()).stream()
            .map(this::getNode)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

I basically can only figure what is happening up to the `.stream()` method call:

1. Get the `Id` of the passed `node` `GraphNode`
2. Get the `Set<String>` from the `connections` `Map` whose key matches the retrieved `Id`

What I don't understand is what is happening here:

```
.map(this::getNode).collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Can someone provide pseudocode to explain this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [:: (double colon) operator in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8)

Comment: Since Xojo has no Set class, you could simply use a Dictionary with a dummy value (e.g. set to nil or true) instead, and storing the items as the Dictionary's keys. For getNode, loop over all Keys and check if any of them matches the id - and if it matches, return that first match. For getConnections, look over the connections Dictionary and get each their node, and place them into a new set (i.e. Dictionary or array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streams are basically glorified for-each loops. Generally, when you see `XXX.stream()` or a method that returns a `Stream<XXX>`, it means "for each thing in `XXX`" and "For each XXX..." respectively.

So, here it says "for each string in the `Set<String>`..."

`map` means "turn each thing into something else", in other words, a *transformation*. With a for loop, it's like this in pseudocode:

```
For Each x In set
    f(x)
Next x
```

`f` is the function that you pass in. In this case, it's `getNode`.

Now, `getNode` returns `T`, so every element in our original set has been transformed into a `T`. The last call is a `collect`, which means to put all these elements back into some collection, or some other object. In this case, we put all these transformed `T`s back into a new `Set`.

The whole code in pseudocode would be:

```
originalSet = connections.get(node.getId())
newSet = []
For Each x In originalSet
    newSet.add(x)
Next x
```

Answer (score 4):

it means `map` the `id` to a `Node` and put (collect) it into a `set`

`this::getNode` translates to: from this class, use getNode on the `id` which is just syntactic sugar for `.map(id -> getNode(id)).collect(Collectors.toSet())`

```
public T getNode(String id) {
        return nodes.stream()
            .filter(node -> node.getId().equals(id))
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No node found with ID"));
    }
```

This code returns the first Node with `id` in nodes Set, `nodes.stream()
.filter(node -> node.getId().equals(id))` will return a set where each node has the `id` passed as an argument, `findFirst()` will return the first node in the set

```
public Set<T> getConnections(T node) {
        return connections.get(node.getId()).stream()
            .map(this::getNode)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
```

since `connections` is a map, `connections.get(node.getId())` will return the value with the key `node.getId()`, then `map(this::getNode)` maps it from `id` to `Node` using `getNode(String id)`, and finally put it into a `set`