# Java: reading from File folder and adding each to ArrayList

Tags: java, file, stream

Consider this piece of code:

```
private static ArrayList<Level> levels = new ArrayList<>();

static {
    try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("levels"))) {
        paths
            .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
            .forEach(levels.add(new Level(file))); //CAN'T DO!!
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
```

I think the code pretty much says what I'm trying to do. I  found this piece of code somewhere and I tried to apply it, to create Level objects from folder with files such as level1.txt, level2.txt, etc. The Level class takes a File as argument.

The forEach method gives out a SyntaxError.

1. What are the "::" in the filter method?
2. Why is the path, fallowed by a new line and 2 methods? Never seen such a thing before.
3. How can I make this work properly?

Comment: "This code does not work." Please supply an adequate error description, including a full copy of the error and edit it into the question.

Comment: 1 may google it (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8). 2 just return line, same as `paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach(levels.add(new Level(file)));` which is Stream (chaining method here)

Comment: You should put a lambda like `(file) -> levels.add(new Level(file))` into the forEach instead of an expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8) explains well what is `:: (double colon)` operator since Java 8
2. Code can be run written on several lines, but this is same as the following. Your calling the method `filter` then calling `forEach` on the object returned by `filter`

   ```
   paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach(levels.add(new Level(file)));
   ```
3. Get it work, you need to define `file` variable this is done with lambda functions

   ```
   paths.filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach(file -> levels.add(new Level(file)));
   ```

---

**NOT POSSIBLE because `walks() throws IOException`**

In case you don't need the `try/catch` you can use `Collectors` to directly build the list

```
private static ArrayList<Level> levels = Files.walk(Paths.get("levels"))
                                              .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                                              .map(file -> new Level(file))
                                              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: The code does not work. I get SyntaxError in levels.add(new Level(file).

Comment: @DanielOscar I got none; So give the exact detail of the error and the constructor of Level class

Comment: The Level constructor just takes a File objects as parameter.

Comment: IDE suggest I change constructor of Level to receive a Path object instead

Comment: @DanielOscar walk gives out instances of Path not File, so you may adapt, use Path or get the file behind the path