# What's the difference between "mapToInt(Integer::intValue)" and "mapToInt(Integer -> Integer.intValue())"

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

I know they have same effect, but why does `Integer::intValue` give an error?

```
public class ResistorColorDuo {
    Map<String, Integer> colValueMap;

    public ResistorColorDuo(Map<String, Integer> colValueMap) {
        colValueMap.put("Black", 0);
        colValueMap.put("Brown", 1);
        colValueMap.put("Red", 2);
        colValueMap.put("Orange", 3);
        colValueMap.put("Yellow", 4);
        colValueMap.put("Green", 5);
        colValueMap.put("Blue", 6);
        colValueMap.put("Violet", 7);
        colValueMap.put("Grey", 8);
        colValueMap.put("White", 9);

        this.colValueMap = colValueMap;
    }

    public int getResistorValue(String... colors) {
        return Arrays.stream(colors).map(i -> colValueMap.get(i) *
                Math.pow(10, colors.length - (Arrays.asList(colors).indexOf(i) + 1)))
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue) // Here occurs an exception
                .sum();
    }
}
```

Above code generated an error:

> None-static method can not be referenced from a static context

While it works well like this:

```
public int getResistorValue(String... colors) {
    return Arrays.stream(colors).map(i -> colValueMap.get(i) *
            Math.pow(10, colors.length - (Arrays.asList(colors).indexOf(i) + 1)))
            .mapToInt(Integer -> Integer.intValue())
            // Here is the difference
            .sum();
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code, don't put an image!

Comment: read also [:: (double colon) operator in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8)

Comment: `Integer::intValue()` results in a compile error.

Comment: @MCEmperor the actual code has `Integer::intValue`, so I guess the `()` is just a typo in the question's title and body.

Comment: Is it just me or those two images are exactly the same? Staring at them for few minutes and can't spot any difference.

Comment: There are same thoroughly.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure the error message you got is very informative (see the error message I got below). However, in your `map` step you are returning the result of `Math.pow()`, which is `double`. Hence your `Stream` becomes a `Stream<Double>`.

Trying to apply `.mapToInt(Integer::intValue)` fails, because `Integer`'s `intValue()` requires an `Integer` instance.

When you use the lambda expression `mapToInt(Integer -> Integer.intValue())`, you should note that `Integer` is just **the lambda parameter name**, so it would have been less confusing to write `mapToInt(n -> n.intValue())`.
Since `n` is a `Double` in this case, that lambda expression actually executes `Double`'s `intValue()`, which works.

For a method reference to work, you need to use `.mapToInt(Double::intValue)`.

EDIT: I tried similar code (I didn't feel like typing all the code from your image):

```
int sum = Stream.of ("1","2","3")
                .map (Integer::valueOf)
                .map(i -> Math.pow(i,2))
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                .sum();
```

and got a much better compilation error message:

> The type Integer does not define intValue(Double) that is applicable here

This is fixed by changing the method reference as follows:

```
int sum = Stream.of ("1","2","3")
                .map (Integer::valueOf)
                .map(i -> Math.pow(i,2))
                .mapToInt(Double::intValue)
                .sum();
```