# how can I replace java code that has double colon

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

There is the following code

```
Grid.Column<Person> firstNameColumn = grid.addColumn(Person::getFirstName).setHeader("First Name");
Grid.Column<Person> lastNameColumn = grid.addColumn(Person::getLastName).setHeader("Last Name");
```

I would like to rewrite it without `::`. The reason is that I need to use a function like `getLastName` to have two parameters like `getLastName(firstname, age)`.

Can you provide me a solution or how to search about it?

Thank you

Comment: `....addColumn(person -> person.getLastName(firstName, age))...` --- Having a method `getLastName` with parameters `firstName` and `age` seems suspicous. I would suggest to thorougly review this change.

Comment: I am just giving an example. I would like for this example to rewrite it the pre 8 version of java

Comment: That is not what you originally asked for. If you want to migrate the code to pre-java8, I recommend [edit]ing the post and changing the actual question. --- May I ask why you want to migrate the code back to pre-java8?

Comment: Double colon is a concise shorthand for a lambda expression which you will see often in Streams and similar.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [:: (double colon) operator in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pre-Java 8 version would conventionally use an anonymous class like this:

```
grid.addColumn(new ValueProvider<Person, String>() {
    @Override
    public String apply(Person person) {
        return person.getLastName();
    }
})
```

But you don't need that to customize the method call. An ordinary lambda will do:

```
grid.addColumn(person -> person.getLastName(foo))
```

As you see, the latter is much more concise. Vaadin's API has been designed to embrace Java 8 features such as functional references, lambdas and streams. JDK8 and newer is also a requirement for modern Vaadin versions to function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda

```
grid.addColumn(person -> person.getLastName(person.getFirstName(),person.getAge());
```

For more info, go to [this site](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/grid-tutorial/basics)