# Is it possible to define a Java Function or BiFunction w/o lambda expression?

Tags: java, lambda

In Java, I have only ever defined "method references" `Function` and `BiFunction` w/ lambda expressions, like so:

```
    private static Function<Integer, Boolean> IsEvenFunc =
            (i) -> (i % 2 == 0);
    private static BiFunction<String, Character, Boolean> ByFirstCharFunc =
            (s, c) -> (s.charAt(0) == c.charValue());
```

```
    CustomList<Integer> numbers = new CustomList<>();
    numbers.append(9);
    numbers.append(42);
    numbers.append(47);
    System.out.println(numbers.toStringBy(IsEvenFunc));

    CustomList<String> names = new CustomList<>();
    names.append("Joe");
    names.append("Jim");
    names.append("Bob");
    System.out.println(names.toStringBy(ByFirstCharFunc, 'J'));
```

However, for teaching purposes, if my students don't yet know lambda syntax, is it possible to create these `Function` and `BiFunction` methods without lambda expressions?

Something like...?

```
   private static BiFunction<String s, Character c, Boolean> ByFirstCharFunc
   {
        return s.charAt(0) == c.charValue();
   }
```

Comment: Use an anonymous inner class.

Comment: Doesn't have to be an anonymous inner class: can be a local class, a top-level class, a nested class, regular class, an enum etc.

Comment: On the whole, there is not a good reason to store functional types in fields. Define them as regular methods instead, which you can invoke functionally via a method reference, or directly via a normal method invocation.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I agree, thank you. I completely forgot about the `::` operator in Java :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always just define it as a regular function/method like this:

```
private static boolean IsEven(int i){
    return i % 2 == 0;
}

private static boolean FirstChar(String s, char c){
    return s.charAt(0) == c;
}
```

Comment: Yea, and then pass the method name w/ the `::` operator right? I guess I so rarely use the `::` operator in Java that I forgot about it... Thx.

Comment: Yes exactly. Here's a more detailed explanation of it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8

Comment: @delrocco Note that `::` is used as a part of a _method reference_. If your students don't yet know lambda expressions, then I'm not sure method references will make much more sense. Perhaps you should be using an anonymous class instead.

Comment: @Slaw, thx. They do understand the concept of a "function pointer" and do work in C++ as well. However, in Java, the only way I knew how to do a "method reference" was by making one of those `Function`s or `BiFunction`s with the lambda syntax. I forgot completely about just using a regular method and passing w/ the `::` operator. Obviously the operator is different in C++, so never remember that in Java :/ My fault.

Comment: @delrocco Yeah, it can get confusing with all the different languages using different terms, or even the same term to mean something else. In Java, a "functional interface" is an interface that has only one abstract method. Every interface in the `java.util.function` package is an example of a "functional interface". A "lambda expression" is one way to declare an implementation of a "functional interface". For example, `a -> System.out.println(a)` is an implementation of a functional interface whose abstract method accepts one argument and returns nothing (e.g. `java.util.function.Consumer`).

Comment: And a "method reference" is another way to declare an implementation of a "functional interface". Using the same example as the "lambda expression" in my previous comment, the "method reference" version would look like `System.out::println`. But whether you use a named class, an anonymous class, a lambda expression, or a method reference, you're still literally defining an implementation of an interface. An actual instance of that interface is created at run-time. In other words, there's no proper first-class "function" type in Java (not sure how C++ function pointers actually work).

Answer (score 3):

You can write a class which implements that interface:

```java
class MatchFirstChar implements Function<String,Boolean> {
  private final char c;
  MatchFirstChar(char c) {
    this.c = c;
  }
  Boolean apply(String s) {
    return s.charAt(0) == c;
  } 
}
```

and then use it:

```java
System.out.println(names.toStringBy(new MatchFirstChar('J')));
```

This is more verbose than any of the other ways of doing this, but I think it introduces the minimum of new concepts.