# Collectors example question on Lambda functions

Tags: java

I'm reading about [Collectors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) and [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).  I have a question regarding some Collectors example code shown here:

```
List<String> list = people.stream().map(Person::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Can I assume the person class has a method as follows?

```
class Person {
   String name;
   String getName() { return name; }
}
```

If so I'm confused about the definition of `map` and `Function<T,R>` as follows:

```
<R> Stream<R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R> mapper)
```

For `Function<>`:
R apply(T t)

**Question** if apply requires an argument as above should I assume `Person` looks as follows with a `static` method or how does above code work?

```
class Person {
   String name;
   String getName() { return name; }
   static String getName(Person p) { return p.getName(); }
}
```

Comment: Both are actually applicable. In the case that you're binding for a `Function<Person, R>`, you can provide either a static method (from anywhere) that consumes a `Person`, _or_ a method of `Person`, both returning `R` (inferred at this point). From a reverse engineering standpoint, you'd go and find out which it is (though getters are _usually_ not static). This is done for you, and if both methods exist when you do the method reference I believe it's a compiler error at the callsite of the method reference (can't check atm)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [:: (double colon) operator in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001427/double-colon-operator-in-java-8)

Answer (score 1):

There is no significant difference between:

```
class Person {
  String getName() { ... }
}
```

and:

```
class Irrelevant {
  static String getName(Person p) { ... }
}
```

In fact, at the class file level they are entirely identical, in the sense that the first argument of a non-static method **is** an instance of its class. This hidden parameter is called the receiver. You can even write it:

```
public class Person {
  String getName(Person this) {}
}
```

The above method would be called with, for example, `somePersonInstance.getName()` - the 'receiver' parameter is **always** passed by sticking a dot in front of the method, and that 'argument' in front of the dot.

When looking at lambda notation, this effect shows up too. The concept `Person::getName`, given that `getName` is a zero-args, non-static method in a class named `Person` that returns a string, turns into a function that accepts a person, and returns a string.

After all, to invoke the method you **must** have an instance of `Person` to do that on. You can't write: `String name = Person.getName();` - that does not compile unless `getName` is static.

You can trivially use `::` to make a function that takes zero arguments and returns a string, e.g. a `Producer<String>`. Simply use an actual argument, instead:

```
Person p = new Person();
Supplier<String> x = p::getName;
Function<Person, String> y = Person::getName;
```

The first example encodes the concept of 'invoking the getName method of this specific instance of person' and the second example encodes the concept of 'invoking the getName method of some person instance; that instance must be supplied'.

hence why the first example 'fits' an interface that takes no arguments (and `Function<Person, String> z = p::getName` wouldn't compile), and the second example 'fits' one that takes 1 arg, namely, a Person instance.

Comment: What if ‘getName’ required an argument other then ‘Person this’ like ‘String getName(int x)’? Would ‘Function<T,R> ‘ still work or would I need ‘ BiFunction<T,U,R>’?

Comment: I’m the first instance of the Supplier, would getName be a static menthod with no arguments?

Comment: @notaorb to the first question: You'd need a `BiFunction`, of course: To invoke the this getName method, you need 2 things: An instance of Person, and an int. It would return a String. That describes a `BiFunction<Person, Integer, String>`.

Comment: To the second question: I don't know what "I'm the first instance of the Supplier" means. `getName` is what it is; the fact that you make a lambda of it doesn't magically add or remove the `static` keyword. If `getName()`'s signature is `public static String getName() {}`, you need nothing at all to call it (no args, and no instance of Person), hence, it would 'fit' if you try to turn that into a `Supplier<String>`; `Supplier<String> s = Person::getName` would thus be allowed, _if_ `getName`'s signature is `static String getName();`.

Answer (score 0):

The receiver object is equivalent to an argument when it comes to method references.

If you take a look at [the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13), you can see:

> The target reference of an instance method (§15.12.4.1) may be provided by the method reference expression using an ExpressionName, a Primary, or super, or it may be provided later when the method is invoked. The immediately enclosing instance of a new inner class instance (§15.9.2) is provided by a lexically enclosing instance of this (§8.1.3).

[More specifically](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1):

> - Second, given a targeted function type with n parameters, a set of potentially applicable methods is identified:
>
>   - If the method reference expression has the form ReferenceType :: [TypeArguments] Identifier, then the potentially applicable methods are:
>
>     - the member methods of the type to search that would be potentially applicable (§15.12.2.1) for a method invocation which names Identifier, has arity n, has type arguments TypeArguments, and appears in the same class as the method reference expression; plus
>     - the member methods of the type to search that would be potentially applicable for a method invocation which names Identifier, has arity n-1, has type arguments TypeArguments, and appears in the same class as the method reference expression.
>
> Two different arities, n and n-1, are considered, to account for the possibility that this form refers to either a static method or an instance method.

If it is a non-static method, it requires one argument less as the receiver type is used for that.

In your case, using `Person::getName` for a `Function<Person,String>` would work for both a `String getName()` or `static String getName(Person person)` method.

If you now have a non-static method with a single (non-receiver) parameter, your functional interface would need to have two parameters in your functional interface:

```java
public class Person{
    public String getName(SomeOtherType someParameter){
        return "something";
    }
}
```

```java
//Function<Person,String> f = Person::getName;//doesn't compile
//Function<SomeOtherType,String> f = Person::getName;//doesn't compile
BiFunction<Person,SomeOtherType,String> f = Person::getName;
```

Comment: I added a comment to the OP. Can you clarify this?

Comment: Are you talking about [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/136745380)? _You_ are the OP in this question or are you referring to it as _other poster_? Yes, `void getName(int i)` would require 2 parameters. I added something regarding that to my answer.

Comment: Yes thanks. Finally I get confused with ‘ T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)’ which is ‘  BiFunction<T,U,R>’ and ‘ R apply(T t, U u)’. Would ‘.reduce(C::red)’ be a member ‘static T red(U x, U y)’ and not having the object instance of the class as the first argument?

Comment: If it is non-static, it's like adding another argument at the beginning.  `reduce(C::red)` doesn't work for `reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator)` since it's missing `identity`.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Can I assume the person class has a method as follows? ..."*

No.  That would be helpful though.

The syntax you're describing is referred to as a *lambda method-reference*.

Here is an excerpt from the following *Java* tutorial.
*[Method References (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)*.

> "... You use [lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to create anonymous methods. Sometimes, however, a lambda expression does nothing but call an existing method. In those cases, it's often clearer to refer to the existing method by name. Method references enable you to do this; they are compact, easy-to-read lambda expressions for methods that already have a name. ...
>
> ...
>
> **Kinds of Method References**
> There are four kinds of method references:
>
> | Kind | Syntax | Examples |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Reference to a static method | ContainingClass::staticMethodName | Person::compareByAge MethodReferencesExamples::appendStrings |
> | Reference to an instance method of a particular object | containingObject::instanceMethodName | myComparisonProvider::compareByName myApp::appendStrings2 |
> | Reference to an instance method of an arbitrary object of a particular type | ContainingType::methodName | String::compareToIgnoreCase String::concat |
> | Reference to a constructor | ClassName::new | HashSet::new |

In other words, it's simpler than writing the following.

```java
map(x -> x.getName())
```

It's worth noting, the newer, *[record class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/language/records.html)*, will infer methods for each parameter.

For example, the following is valid.

```java
record Person(String name) { }
Person p = new Person("abc");
String s = p.name();
```